# IdentityServer4 still logged in after restart

Tags: identityserver4

I set up an IdentityServer4 instance on localhost.
I log in from the ui sample screen, without checking remember my login.
Then I restart my server, and i am still logged in.
On what does IS4 rely to retrieve session / user data ? Sessions are not persisted, so I assume it does get the data from the cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 uses [cookie authentication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html).

Since the browser and IdentityServer4 are on the same machine, this means that your browser is configured to preserve cookies. If you change this to 'remove cookies on close', the behaviour is that you are logged out on restart.

About the token: on sign-in IdentityServer4 sends an access token that is stored in a (https) cookie. The access token can be of two types, [refence and self-contained (JWT)](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html). Most likely you are using JWT tokens, though the behaviour is probably the same for reference tokens.

A JWT token has certain characteristics:

- self-contained (lives on its own)
- identifies the user based on the information stored in the token
- can't be altered
- lives until it expires
- once issued, it can't easily be revoked

The server uses signing credentials to encode the JWT token. It also needs these credentials to decode and validate the token. As long as nothing changes, the token can be validated.

In your case the signin credentials seem to be fixed (certificate?), since restarting IdentityServer4 doesn't affect the validation of the token. The browser on the other hand still has the token stored in the cookie. So nothing actually changed on restart. IdentityServer4 is in the same state and the access token was simply read from the cookie.

If you would have used DeveloperSigningCredentials instead (`AddDeveloperSigningCredential`), the behaviour is that the access token is not valid. As the key to decode and validate the token changed on restart. And when the access token is lost (cookie was removed) you'll have to login again.

Comment: I think this is what is happening. I will try this with a proper certificate and post back if it resolved the issue

Comment: I used a proper certificate but still have issues on token validation upon restart. I forgot to mention that I use a docker image of IS4. I see the following on startup : `User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest`. After restart on token validation the key is not found as I have no volume. I guess the best practice would be to mount a volume or persist keys on a redis cache ?

Comment: @RomainWilbert You should add this information to the question